# lightbox_me - open different popups on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a page with multiple popups on the same page. I want the first popup to open on page load which I can get to work with

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jquery.lightbox_me.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" > 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#sign_up").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { $('#sign_up').find ('input:first').focus()}});
}); // document ready 

</script> 

<body onload="$('#sign_up').trigger('click');">
```

But then I want the user to be able to click a link in that popup that will stay on the same page but open up a different popup. And again from the second popup I want the user to be able to click a link to open a 3rd popup.

Using this code I can click a link in the first popup (sign_up) Click here which does open the second popup (sign1) but the first popup is still behind (I can see it because the second popup is smaller)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        function launch() {
             $('#sign_up').lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { $('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()}});
        }

        $('#try-1').click(function(e) {
            $("#sign_up").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
                $("#sign_up").find("input:first").focus();
            }});

            e.preventDefault();
        });


        $('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        function launch() {
             $('#sign1').lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { $('#sign1').find('input:first').focus()}});
        }

        $('#try-2').click(function(e) {
            $("#sign1").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
                $("#sign1").find("input:first").focus();
            }});

            e.preventDefault();
        });


        $('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');
    });
</script>
```

I am very new to jquery and have basically been trying to copy and tweak current code but to no joy.